# hold-to-copy in uiwebview subclass

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

For my app, I subclassed UIWebView (the method described here http://ryan-brubaker.blogspot.com/2009/01/iphone-sdk-uiwebview.html).

I did this so that I could intercept touch events; when I detect certain types of taps, I perform the corresponding custom action, and then pass the event along to the underlying UIWebView.

So for example I can doubletap the view to make a toolbar appear/disappear, but a single tap on a link works the same as a regular UIWebView.

Under 3.0, Everything works just the same as it did under 2.2.1 (my doubletap + the standard single tap and scroll actions), but hold-to-copy does not.

I thought perhaps there was something new in UIResponder that I had to override, but as far as I can tell it's the same.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't have to do anything special, as long as you're passing all the touch events through. It's certainly possible to disable that functionality using `-webkit-user-select: none;` in your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    body {-webkit-user-select:none;}
</style>
```